# Should I ever clear the interrupted flag and not throw InterruptedException or terminate?

Tags: java, multithreading

I understand that thread interruption status should be cleared when it has been delivered and handled by the code responsible for the thread life-cycle. It seems to me that the only code that should ever request interruption is one that the Thread is coded to cooperate with (usually one that created the thread) as "interruption" status seems to be open to interpretation.

The only scenario I can think of is some a application container that has been requested to abort some work. To do so, it interrupts the managed threads and does some clean-up and the threads continue. However, this is overly complex as allowing threads to terminate and starting new ones is much easier to do in practice.

When does it makes sense for a thread to "handle" interruption status and not terminate?

Comment: I have this Image uploading thing and I have an Array of images. When uploading a single image taking 1 min or more; I will interrupt it but I will not terminate the thread since I still need to upload some other images.

Comment: OK, but what if the image completes just before you interrupt it?

Comment: Not a problem at all since the array I am mentioning is a queue, which adds those failed upload back to the queue. Which means I can still reupload it in the next loop cycles.

Comment: Almost never.  If someone interrupts your thread, it means they want you to stop what you’re doing and clean up gracefully.  Threads which ignore interrupts are rogue threads, and there are many Stack Overflow posts complaining that such threads (almost always in third party libraries) can’t be shut down.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, an interrupt means whatever you want it to mean.  The problem is, suppose the interrupt happens when your code is calling a library routine;  What did the library author think it was supposed to mean?  *Hopefully*, the lib author thought it meant, "abort the current operation, but leave everything in a consistent state in case the client wants to start another one."  But if it happens when that library is in the middle of calling some *other* library that some *other* yahoo wrote...

The only truly safe thing to do is shut the whole program down.